# SQL Server 2012 won't connect after installing a second instance for tabular models

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas-tabular

I've had this identical problem on several laptops.  The sequence of events is this:

1. I installed SQL Server 2012 with a named instance called `SQL2012`, to include SSRS, SSIS and SSAS multi-dimensional.  This works fine.
2. I installed service pack 2.
3. I installed a second named instance called `TABULAR`, which includes only SSAS (tabular model).

The problem then comes when I try to connect to the original `SQL2012` instance - it won't connect and shows this:

[image]

If I go into Configuration Manager, I see this:

[image]

If I go into management console and right-click on this SQL Server service, I can start it:

[image]

This solves the problem of connecting to the database engine, but the services still show up as an error in configuration manager (even after refreshing).

A few notes which may help:

- I'm running Windows 10 Professional (but the problem also showed up on laptops running Windows 7 Professional)
- I have SSMS, SSRS, SSIS and SSAS (and also SQL Server Agent) set up to run automatically
- If I restart the laptop, I'm back to square one and have to restart the service again
- the `tabular` instance works fine, and I can connect to it OK

I've tried to find other people with the same problem, but can't! Can anyone assist please?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you rerun the SP2 installer and see if it needs to be reapplied or applied to the TABULAR instance?

Comment: Is the SQL2012 instance set to auto start in the management console? Obviously you will have to manually start it after reboot if not. I'm pretty sure you know that already.

Comment: I reran the SP2 on the original SQL2012 instance.  I haven't run it on the newer TABULAR instance, but will do when I'm next back in the office.  The SQL2012 instance was indeed set to auto-start.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess... I can see on the screen the other instance of SQL Server installed on your machine (SQLEXPRESS) so, maybe you have other SQL Server instances of another version, 2008 for example... If so, maybe you need to install the latest SP on them.

Check quote from [here](http://thesqldude.com/2012/12/05/sql-server-2012-configuration-manager-wmi-error-remote-procedure-call-failed-0x800706be/)

> If you have SQL Server 2012 running side-by-side on the same machine
>   with SQL Server 2008/2008 R2, then you need to have SQL Server 2008
>   SP3 or later (or) SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 or later.